# how to save the value in the database in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

this is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    choices = (
    ('C', 'C'),
    ('C++', 'C++'),
    ('Java', 'Java'),
    ('Python', 'Python'),
    )
    intrest = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=choices)
```

this is my views.py

```
if request.method=="POST":
        choice=request.POST['choice']
```

this choice has the value which i want to add to my database.how to add this choice in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the basics this will help :)

```
from .models import Profile

def profile(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        choice = request.POST['choice']
        profile = Profile(name = name, choice = choice)
        profile.save()
        
        return render(request,"example.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new model called choices and use ForeignKey or ManyToMany. Alternatively, you could create a global config.py file (stored at the project level) and import it.

Answer (score 0):

You should import Profile model and create a profile object. Then after you add a parameter to the profile object, just save it.

**views.py**

```
from .models import Profile

def profile(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        choice = request.POST['choice']
        profile_content = Profile(name = name, choice = choice)
        profile_content.save()
        
        return render(request,"example.html")
```